# NavigationDrawer with childfragments and activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a Activity A, a ListFragment L and 2 Fragments F1 and F2.

When the app is launched, A is created, which loads L. Based on what user clicks, it is replaced by F1 or F2

I have implemented a Navigation Drawer which shows certain items to the user. However, since I have implemented the Navigation Drawer in the Activity, it shows for all the Fragments. but i want show A is visible

(Very much similar to Googles Gmail app. When the user is on the main screen - the drawer is present. When user taps to open an email, the drawer changes to back button)

I am not sure how to translate the above code. thanks in advance

Comment: Its use of drawer toggle, if you disable it for particular fragment, it will be back button.

Comment: sorry,i did not understand what you are saying

Comment: There is function disableToggle() and it will not show the drawer icon and show back icon, but still drawer can be opened from left swipe(in gmail also). If you want I will provide demo code.

Comment: k please provide demo code.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner fragment(like view mail)

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
super.onPause();
((MyActivity) getActivity()).enableToggle();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
((MyActivity) getActivity()).disableToggle();
}
```

I hope there will be 'NavigationDrawerFragment'in your activity, add this methods:

```
public void disableToggle()
{
if (mNavigationDrawerFragment != null)
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.disableToggle();
}

public void enableToggle()
{
if (mNavigationDrawerFragment != null)
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.enableToggle();
}
```

In NavigationDrawerFragment add this methods:
Also check that you are using **android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;**

```
public void disableToggle()
{
if (mDrawerToggle != null)
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
}

public void enableToggle()
{
if (mDrawerToggle != null)
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
}
```

Edit: see snapshots for above code

MainFragment

[image: 2]

DetailFragment

[image: 2]

Comment: Have u called getActionBar().setHomeAsUpUnabled(true);? call it in disableToggle() in MainActivity.

Comment: its not going back to drawer. i need drawer as well as activity.

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you mean its not showing drawer button? Have you added methods in proper classes? The middle one is to be added in MainActivity. and Dont add first part in first fragment.

Comment: yaa....i removed that first part method in first fragment.then its working like a normal drawer.but its not my actual output.. Did You get my question what i asked to implement? if are not got.please tell me i will explain again

Comment: Ok tell me again, or put any sample image for detail.

Comment: image is not supporting here

Comment: You said "the drawer is present. When user taps to open an email, the drawer changes to back button" is this not happening?

Comment: I have attached snapshot? Is this what you wanted?

Comment: no..thats not my problem. i too got that navigation drawer